# Call Multiple Events on Same Function

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I created a few items on a page and am validating those items using JavaScript:

```
function formvalidation() {         
    var f1 = $x('P1_FIRST_NAME');
     
    if( f1.value == "" ) {
        //alert("Enter First Name"); 
        f1.style.backgroundColor = "red";
        f1.focus();
        return false;
    }
    else {
        f1.style.backgroundColor = "white";    
    )
}
```

To call the above function I am using the `onclick` event. Now, if a user uses the <kbd>tab</kbd> key to go the item, how to provide two events call on the same function?

I am calling the function this way:

```
onclick="formvalidation()";onkeyup="formvalidation()";
```

Please suggest me how to call multiple events.

Comment: Do you want code that isn't a syntax error too? ;)

Comment: are these button events (`onClick` and `onkeyup`)?

Comment: I hope you must be knowing about the onblur event.

Comment: When user try using tab key this validation must work. I am calling this on each item when user clicks or use tab keyonclick="formvalidation()";onblur="formvalidation()";  is this method correct to call multiple events please suggest

Answer (score 0):

Use the `onfocus` event.  The `onfocus` event is fired whenever the control receives focus, whether via click or keyboard.  Similarly, you may find the `onblur` event useful.

Answer (score 0):

Try `onfocus` event. So If user click or come via pressing tab key this event will be call.